# Assigning two views to a single Container View using swift in iOS 8

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to assign two view controllers to a Container View using the Interface Builder. I tried to do so, but whenever I try to "embed" the second view controller to my Container View, instead of adding another VC to it, it just replaces the one that was embedded already.

Ultimately, my main goal is to have a screen that has the following elements (in order, from top to bottom):

-A navigation bar
-A view of height 50 that contains a segmented controller (which will switch between tableVCs)
-A main view, which will contain my Container view
-A tabbed bar

My current setup is almost as described above. Here is a picture:
[image]

The view controller I am interested in the most is in the one with the highlighted container(HomeViewController). The approach I am currently using is hacky, because I currently have 2 container views, one on top of another, and they embed the 2 table view controllers depicted to the right (one per container).

I do not like this approach very much because both containers get instantiated whenever the main VC (Home View Controller) is instantiated, therefore making 2 network calls by default to load their content, possibly slowing down the device and maybe using more memory than needed.

Ideally, I would load the content of one table view controller that is mapped to one of the segmented controls. Then, I would have a mechanism that somehow instantiates the second table view controller whenever I go to the second button in the segmented control (and possibly deallocating/getting rid of the other VCs), and so on with the third. Or somehow be able to display/alternate between 2 or more view controllers in an area (view) inside my HomeViewController.

Currently I have this simple code that switches (hides and shows) between container views in my HomeViewController:

```
@IBAction func segmentChanged(sender: AnyObject) {
        switch segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex{
        case 0:
            println("index1 selected")
            containerView1.hidden = false
            containerView2.hidden = true
            break
        case 1:
            println("index2 selected")
            containerView1.hidden = true
            containerView2.hidden = false
            break
        default:
            containerView1.hidden = false
            containerView2.hidden = true
            break
        }
    }
```

As I said, this only switches between the views that are loaded already in my view controller, with the data in them already.

I just wanted to see if what I am trying to code is doable, or if I am actually tackling the problem the right way, although I doubt I am doing so.

Thank you for reading my post and for your advice in advance.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Add embed segue to NavigationController, add ViewController as rootViewController to NavigationController, from rootViewController add as many segue as you wish. To load controller you need just override segue class to push without navigation.

```
class NoAnimationSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {

   override func perform() {
      self.sourceViewController.navigationController?.pushViewController(self.destinationViewController, animated: false)
   }

}
```

[image]